# MWPhotoBrowser not working, giving me error Photos/Photos.h file not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mwphotobrowser

I have added MWPHotoBrowse to my project by insalling the pod gem, creating the podfile in the project, and then running pod install (with no error, and it said it installed MWPhotoBrowser)

My podfile looks like this:

```
 platform :ios, '7.0'

 target 'Groupiq' do

 pod "MWPhotoBrowser"

 end

 target 'GroupiqTests' do

 end
```

And yet every time I build I get this error:

> Photos/Photos.h file not found in MWPhoto.

Any idea how I can fix this?

EDIT: I just removed my pods installation, and just added the library manually, getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the .xcworkspace file after install ? If you open the simple .xcodeproject file, this won't work, since it will not find dependencies contained in Pods project.

Comment: Ya, I did that. I just removed my pods installation, and just added the library manually, getting the exact same error.

Comment: It seems that the error comes from the latest version of MWPHotoBrowser, which uses Photos library dependency..  have you updated your cocoapods by using sudo gem update cocoapods ? Because "Photos" framework is a link by a weak_framework ?

Comment: I've tested succesfully to update this library with cocoapods, on my existing project and it worked. Do you have customized the "Other Linker Flags" value in your main project properties ? You must have $(inherited) value in the list to have the link work